# Can something be both a subject and an object in a sentence?

Tags: grammar

For example:

"The gladiators killed bulls but not before they killed quite a few gladiators as well."

In that sentence, "gladiators" is the subject, the verb is "killed" and "bulls" is the object but "bulls" is also the subject doing the verb, "killed" (2nd) as well. It would appear that bulls is both an object and a subject, am I correct?

Comment: 'Subject' and 'object' are context dependent and defined as fulfilling syntactical roles in a clause. 'The gladiators' and 'they' are subjects here; 'bulls' and 'they' have the same **referent**. In 'Jill hit John', 'Jill' is the subject, but in the alternative version 'John was hit by Jill', 'John' is the subject.

Comment: I think that's just a badly written sentence.  On the face if it it sounds like you're saying the gladiators killed each other as well as the bulls.

Comment: Just insert "other" before the second "gladiators".

Answer (score 2):

It's clauses that have subjects and (sometimes) objects, not sentences.

> The gladiators killed bulls…

*The gladiators* is the subject, *killed* the verb, *bulls* the object.

> …not before they killed quite a few gladiators as well.

*they* is the subject, *killed* the verb, *a few gladiators* the object.

The sentence doesn't have a subject and object, it has two subjects and two objects.

We can consider reflexive middle voice as having the same thing as subject and object of the same clause:

> He shaved.

Since *he* is both the person who shaved and the person who was shaved. This is debatable, and some would say *he* was only the subject.

Note that the following do not have the same subject and object:

> He shaved himself.
>
> John shaved John.

While the words refer to the same person, and in the last case are also the same word, they are still different words, one the subject and one the object.